# How to bind selected date to viewmodel in xamarin forms using date picker

Tags: c#, datepicker, xamarin.forms

I have a DatePicker as below:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="MyDatePicker" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Date="{Binding BookingDate}" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

I want to get a newly selected date in my ViewModel but when I add binding for DateSelected:

```
DateSelected="{Binding MyViewModelJob}"
```

it will not work (the page with DatePicker won't even open).

What should I do in XAML and in my ViewModel to get the date?

Comment: Try `DateSelected="new_dateSelected"` and `private void new_dateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e) { //Do your thing }`. Based on [DatePicker DateSelected Event Not Fired if the date doesn't change?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47570/datepicker-dateselected-event-not-fired-if-the-date-doesnt-change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateSelected is not a bindable property, it is an Event on the DatePicker type. If you want to change the date via a property on your viewmodel, you will just have to change the "BookingDate" property, which you have already attached to the Date property of the DatePicker.

Heres some pseudocode:

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged //Implement INPC to update the view when a property changes
{

    private DateTime bookingDate;
    public DateTime BookingDate 
    {
        get { return bookingDate; }
        set 
        { 
            bookingDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BookingDate");   //Call INPC Interface when property changes, so the view will know it has to update
        }
    }

    private void ChangeDate(DateTime newDate)
    {
        BookingDate = newDate;  //Assing your new date to your property
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In DatePicker is Date. And this is bindable property.

In XAML:

```
<DatePicker
         HeightRequest="40"
         Date ="{Binding StartDate}" 
/>
```

And in ViewModel you can write:

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    DateTime _startdate;
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get
        {   
                return _startdate;
        }
        set
        {
            _startdate = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("StartDate");

        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And after this you can in all of your ViewModel use StartDate, so you can get or set your Date.